# Android Dagger 2.14 setup

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am trying to figure out how to setup android project with dagger 2, but I am doing something wrong. Dagger 2 and android dependancy injection is relatively new concepts for me.

Here is my setup.

```
// App.java root of the application
public class App extends DaggerApplication {
    @Override
    protected AndroidInjector<? extends DaggerApplication> applicationInjector() {
        AppComponent appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.create();
        appComponent.inject(this);
        return appComponent;
    }
}

// AppComponent.java component
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class, 
        AppBuilder.class, 
        SplashModule.class,
        AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<App> {
}

// AppBuilder.java module which bootstraps activities
@Module
public abstract class AppBuilder {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract SplashActivity splashActivityInjector();
}
```

I also have activities which extend DaggerAppCompatActivity and SplashModule which handles dependancy injection in SplashActivity

Now this setup is working and I am able to inject MVP pattern presenter in my SplashActivity like this:

```
// inside SplashActivity
@Inject
SplashContract.Presenter mPresenter;
```

And MVP view in presenter

```
// SplashPresenter
@Inject
SplashContract.View view;
```

So far so good. But now I want to do additional injection in my presenter:

```
@Inject
AppDataManager appDataManager;
```

AppDataManager class requires application context to be constructed. And also I need only 1 instance of AppDataManager per application. I am not sure how to do this, there are quite a few example but they use different
Dagger 2 versions and since I am not really experienced with it gets confusing.

I tried setting up additional AppModule class which should handle AppDataManager provision, but it crashes on runtime.

```
// AppModule.java
@Module
public class AppModule {
    private Context mContext;

    public AppModule(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Context provideContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    AppDataManager provideAppDataManager(Context context) {
        return new AppDataManager(context);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? (I suspect I should define AppModule differently).

**EDIT Logcat:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.domain.application, PID: 16075
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.domain.application/com.domain.application.ui.splash.SplashActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.domain.application.data.AppDataManager.isUserLoggedIn()' on a null object reference
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.domain.application.data.AppDataManager.isUserLoggedIn()' on a null object reference
   at com.domain.application.ui.splash.SplashPresenter.openNextActivity(SplashPresenter.java:25)
   at com.domain.application.ui.splash.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:20)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6955)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: could you provide the logcat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your `AppComponent` as follow:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class, AppBuilder.class, AppModule.class})
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App>
```

Make your `App` use it:

```
public class App extends Application implements HasActivityInjector, HasSupportFragmentInjector {

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingActivityInjector;

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> dispatchingFragmentInjector; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // Pay attention here: you have to initialize your `AppModule` with the context. 
        // Without it, Dagger won't be able to provide a `Context`.
        // Since your AppDataManager needs a context to be provided, Dagger will also fail to provide it.
        DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .appModule(AppModule(this)) // <-- don't forget this line
            .build()
            .inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return dispatchingActivityInjector;
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Fragment> supportFragmentInjector() {
        return dispatchingFragmentInjector;
    }
}
```

Your `AppBuilder` should look like this:

```
@Module
public abstract class AppBuilder {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {SplashModule.class})
    abstract SplashActivity splashActivityInjector();
}
```

and your `AppModule`:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
    private Context mContext;

    public AppModule(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Context provideContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    AppDataManager provideAppDataManager(Context context) {
        return new AppDataManager(context);
    }
}
```

Your `SplashModule`:

```
@Module
abstract class SplashModule {

    @Binds
    abstract SplashContract.View provideView(SplashActivity activity)

    @Binds
    abstract SplashContract.Presenter providePresenter(SplashPresenter presenter)
}
```

Use constructor injection with your presenter:

```
@Inject
public SplashPresenter(SplashContract.View view, AppDataManager manager) {
    mView = view;
    mManager = manager;
}
```

and finally inject your presenter inside `SplashActivity` with `@Inject SplashContract.Presenter presenter`. For this to work, make sure that your `SplashActivity` extends `DaggerAppCompatActivity`. Also, `SplashActivity` has to implement `SplashContract.View` as well as `SplashPresenter` has to implement `SplashContract.Presenter`.

If your `AppComponent` is not declared as `Singleton`, every time you inject an `AppDataManager` you'd have a different instance. Marking it with `@Singleton` made sure that you receive the same object as long as the component providing it is alive. Since your `AppComponent` is tied to your `Application`, your component won't die and will therefore deliver the same instance of your objects.

As a rule of thumb, you should use constructor injection whenever it's possible. By using it, Dagger will inject every parameters needed to create your object. Also, marking a constructor with `@Inject` makes it part of the dependency graph: it can now be injected without having to create a `@Provides` method.

You have to initialize the `AppModule` manually because it uses a non-empty constructor. At this point, Dagger has no clue on how to provide a `Context` (which is used to create your `AppModule`). If a module installed on your `AppComponent` uses the default empty constructor, you don't have to initialize it yourself.

The `@Binds` annotation is used to reduce further boilerplate. It must be applied on an abstract function which has a single parameter whose type is assignable to the return type. In your case, the parameter `SplashScreenActivity` implements the return type `SplashContract.View`: whenever you inject a `SplashContract.View`, Dagger will provide the interface implementation of `SplashScreenActivity`.

Comment: This solution work. But this leaves me very confused. Why AppComponent needs to be @Singleton? Why do I need provide constructor dependancies instead of property ones? Why I need to use @Binds over @Provides? And why I need to instantiate AppModule manually?

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful.

Comment: Why don't you inherit from DaggerApplication?

Answer (score 1):

First, add a custom `Builder` interface and the method `inject` that receives you `App` as a parameter to your `AppComponent`:

```
@Component.Builder
interface Builder {

    @BindsInstance
    Builder application(App app);

    AppComponent build();

}

void inject(App app);
```

Also, add the `@Singleton` annotation to your `AppComponent` interface.

Then build your app. In your `App` class, use your custom builder to inject your `App` instance:

```
AppComponent appComponent = DaggerAppComponent
            .builder()
            .application(this)
            .build();
    appComponent.inject(this);
```

Update your `AppModule` to provide the context properly:

```
@Provides
Context providesContext(App app) {
    return app.getApplicationContext();
}

@Singleton @Provides
AppDataManager provideAppDataManager(Context context) {
    return new AppDataManager(context);
}
```

And finally, make sure that your calling the `inject` method of  `AndroidInjection` on your activity before the `super` call:

```
AndroidInjection.inject(this)
```